# Detect a Machine or a Human with AMD

Tags: sip, asterisk, pjsip

I'm implementing an asterisk server.

I'm using PJSUA to send a wav file to my phone, passing through the asterisk server.

Here is my extension.conf

```
[appel-sortant] ; Initialisation                                                                                                                                                                                                             
exten => _X.,1,Set(LOOP=0)
exten => _X.,2,Set(MAX=3)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
exten => _X.,n,Set(ASTREINTE=${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Goto(astreinte,${EXTEN},10)                                                                                                                                                                               
exten => _X.,500,Hangup

[astreinte]
exten => _X.,10,Dial(SIP/${ASTREINTE}@forfait-ovh,20,gS(10))
exten => _X.,n,AMD()
exten => _X.,n,NoOp(${DIALSTATUS}) ; Here got ANSWER status
exten => _X.,n,NoOp(${AMDSTATUS}) ; Here got MACHINE or NOTSURE
exten => _X.,n,Hangup
```

My problem are :

1/ When i call my phone number while sending a wav file from PJSUA, the AMDSTATUS is MACHINE at the end of the call

2/ If I call with pjsua without wav file, I got a AMDSTATUS = NOTSURE.

Is AMD() detecting answering machines or caller machine ?

Here is my Pjsua line file :

```
pjsua --null-audio --local-port=5061 --id sip:username@192.168.X.X --registrar sip:192.168.X.X --realm * --username username --password password --auto-play --play-file=./sounds/sound.wav sip:0123456789@192.168.X.X
```

I'm currently on asterisk 1.6.2.9-2squeeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to play around with the settings in the [AMD](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_AMD) function.  You have the following parameters:

```
AMD([initialSilence[,greeting[,afterGreetingSilence[,totalAnalysis Time[,miniumWordLength[,betweenWordSilence[,maximumNumberOfWords[,silenceThreshold[,maximumWordLength]]]]]]]]])

initialSilence - Is maximum initial silence duration before greeting.
    If this is exceeded set as MACHINE
greeting - is the maximum length of a greeting.
    If this is exceeded set as MACHINE
afterGreetingSilence - Is the silence after detecting a greeting.
    If this is exceeded set as HUMAN
totalAnalysis Time - Is the maximum time allowed for the algorithm
    to decide HUMAN or MACHINE
miniumWordLength - Is the minimum duration of Voice considered to be a word
betweenWordSilence - Is the minimum duration of silence after a word to consider the audio that follows to be a new word
maximumNumberOfWords - Is the maximum number of words in a greeting
    If this is exceeded set as MACHINE
silenceThreshold - How long do we consider silence
maximumWordLength - Is the maximum duration of a word to accept.
    If exceeded set as MACHINE
```

Based on the pattern of silence, sound, and length of sound detected from the pjsua application, you should be able to ascertain the correct values for those parameters to achieve the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - AMD() detects if an answering machine picked up.  The possible values it could return are:
MACHINE | HUMAN | NOTSURE | HANGUP

I don't know the inner-workings of the function, but if you're playing a wav file - amd() probably thinks it indeed is an answering machine.

It seems your scenario is providing the correct results. Your dial-plan and Pjsua line seem fine to me.